# How to use Pydantic base schema to n number of child schema

Tags: python-3.x, json-api, pydantic

I'm new to pydantic, I want to define pydantic schema and fields for the below python dictionary which in the form of JSONAPI standard

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "string",
    "attributes":{
           "title": "string",
           "name": "string"
          }
}
```

I managed to achieve this by defining multiple schemas like below,

```
class Child2(BaseModel):
    title: str
    name: str

class Child1(BaseModel):
    type: str
    attributes: Child2

class BaseParent(BaseModel):
    data: Child1
```

But, I will be having multiple json request with the same json API structure as below,

```
example 1 {
  "data": {
    "type": "string",
    "attributes":{
           "source": "001",
           "status": "New"
          }
}

example 2 {
  "data": {
    "type": "string",
    "attributes":{
           "id": "001"
          }
}
```

If you look into the above python dictionary, Values only under the attributes object are different. So, is there any way that I can define a parent marshmallow scheme for { "data": { "type": "string", "attributes":{ } } } and use that parent schema for all child schema's.

Comment: Please be aware that an attribute must not named `id` accordingly to JSON:API specification: "a resource can not have an attribute and relationship [...] named type or id." https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-fields

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer finally, Hope this will help someone.

Pydantic 'create_model' concept will help to resolve this kind of requirement by passing child schema as one of the field values to create_model.

```
class Child(BaseModel):
   title: str
   name: str
 
class BaseParent(BaseModel):
    data: create_model('BaseParent', type=(str, ...), attributes=(Child, ...))
```

And this will frame a BaseParent schema structure as below,

```
data=BaseParent(type='id', attributes=Child2(title='test002', name='Test'))
```